# Where to find/buy a good puppy?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection

Hello I'm currently looking for a dog for my family and I'm not really sure where to start my research. In the past I've always gotten a dog through a friend of a friend but we recently moved and I don't know anyone around me with puppies.

I have tried to look online, but I could only really find pure breeds or expensive "designer" dogs. I'm really just looking for a well rounded mutt for my family of two teenage boys and a big yard.

I looked at the dog shelters but they didn't have very many dogs for adoption and now I think I'm out of options.

Where can I find a puppy (under 6 months old) in rural Michigan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many rescue organizations work out of volunteer's private homes and can be difficult to find. Additionally, even if an organization lists their available pets on their web site, that list may not be up to date, especially during times when puppies may have a high turnover rate. You may have better luck locating a rescue in your area and calling them instead of just looking at their listings on a web site.

Finally, if there aren't any puppies in the area, let the rescue groups know that you specifically want a puppy and will wait for it. Ask them if you should call back (and how often) or if they keep a list and will call you if a puppy becomes available.

The following resources can be used to help you locate a local puppy:

- Look on a national pet search database such as [Petfinder](https://www.petfinder.com/) or [The Shelter Pet Project](http://theshelterpetproject.org/).
- Some stores also hold adoption events. A list/map of these stores can be found on [No Pet Store Puppies](http://nopetstorepuppies.com/map-goodstores).
- Call local veterinary offices and/or grooming salons. They may know of puppies looking for new homes.
- Look for local classified advertisements.

  - In my area there are a large number of "yardsale" Facebook groups and puppies are often advertised there.
  - Craigslist often also sees a lot of pet postings.
  - If you have a community forum or mailing list, you can usually find advertisements there (or can make a post yourself asking for references).
  - Some community oriented stores/studios (like my local yoga studio) will have a community message board for advertisements

When you find a puppy you should consider if you are ethically comfortable with how the puppy was produced and raised. Many folks find [backyard breeders](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/what-is-the-procedure-for-adopting-a-purebred-dog-in-the-united-states/6804#6804) and [puppy mills](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reputable-breeder-and-a-pet-mill) distasteful and using these methods to find a puppy may turn up a dog from these origins. Puppies produced from these sources may be "purebred" but often were not screened for health/behavior problems that may surface later in life.

Answer (score 4):

So many family dogs are abandoned when their previous owners become tired of caring for the animal.

So many fighting / racing / breeding dogs are scheduled for euthanasia when their owners deem them to be worthless.

Please consider adopting a dog from a shelter or organisation dedicated to placing ex breeding / racing / fighting dogs into good homes with loving families. So many beautiful dogs waiting for a home with so much character.

If you look in the internet some more, you should find, depending on your location, organisations that look to shelter all types of dogs and place them with suitable new owners.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people are against it, but try Craigslist; some people put up ads for accident litters or animals they can't care for anymore, so check that out. Also, try going to your local vet; sometimes they are aware of some foster dogs that are in need of a home.